# Moving Divs in the DOM - Using Selectors to Grab Specific Elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

If I have these elements:

```
<div id="item_container">
   <li class="dev_item" data-div="1">sdfsdf</li>
   <li class="dev_item" data-div="2">Izxctem 1</li>
   <li class="dev_item" data-div="3">Item 1</li>
   <li class="dev_item" data-div="4">Item 1</li>
</div>
```

And I want to prepend only the last two '#dev_item' list items (with data-div = 3 and 4) into this div:

```
<div id='prepend_here'></div>
```

How do I select those specific items?

I figured out how to select all of the items:

```
$('#item_container>li').detach().prependTo('#prepend_here');
```

But how do I select the items by the data-div attribute?

Thanks alot,

Taylor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#item_container .dev_item').slice(-2).prependTo('#prepend_here');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the attribute-equals selector:

```
$('li[data-div="3"], li[data-div="4"]').detach().prependTo('#prepend_here');
```

Reference:

- [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).

Comment: I can't edit, but I think there's a minor typo, and the first should be `li[data-div="3"]`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in my situation. Possibly a problem with my code

Comment: @Doug, yeah...um...oops. Thanks for the comment, edited the correction in. :)